# How to design my JavaFX Service / Tasks for calculating 4 checksums of a file?

Tags: java, javafx, architecture, software-design

I'm new to JavaFX and have a problem with the design / architecture of my software.

My use case is:

1. User inserts file(s) into my software per File Chooser or per Drag&Drop
2. Read meta data of this file like filename, path, length (filesize) etc.
3. calculate different checksums of each file
4. save all information (meta data and calculated checksums) in a SQLite-Datase

At the moment I only calculate one checksum because I don't know how to wait for the other services. And I think my design is not very smart. Do you have any suggestions?

`dev.kanka.checksumsharer.ChecksumSharerApplication#handleDragAndDropFiles`:

```
private void handleDragAndDropFiles(Dragboard dragboard) {
    List<File> newFiles = dragboard.getFiles();
    logger.info("Dropped files: " + newFiles);
    FileUtil.handleNewFiles(newFiles);
}
```

`dev.kanka.checksumsharer.utils.FileUtil#handleNewFiles`

```
public static void handleNewFiles(List<File> files) {
    for (java.io.File file : files) {
        KnkFile knkFile = new KnkFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

        ChecksumCalculatorService sha256service = new ChecksumCalculatorService(knkFile, Algorithm.SHA_256);
        sha256service.start();
        sha256service.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            knkFile.setSha256(sha256service.getValue());
            logger.debug(knkFile);
            // TODO: I could call the second service here?
            FileDAO.insertFile(knkFile);
        });



//      ChecksumCalculatorService sha512Service = new ChecksumCalculatorService(file, Algorithm.SHA_512);
//      ChecksumCalculatorService sha3384Service = new ChecksumCalculatorService(file, Algorithm.SHA3_384);
//      ChecksumCalculatorService sha3512Service = new ChecksumCalculatorService(file, Algorithm.SHA3_512);
//
//      sha512Service.start();
//      sha3384Service.start();
//      sha3512Service.start();

    // TODO: How can I insert this one file after calculating all checksums? Software Architecture Question...

    }
}
```

`ChecksumCalculatorService:`

```
package dev.kanka.checksumsharer.hash;

import dev.kanka.checksumsharer.models.KnkFile;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class ChecksumCalculatorService extends Service<String> {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    private KnkFile knkFile;
    private Algorithm algorithm;

    public ChecksumCalculatorService(KnkFile f, Algorithm algorithm) {
        this.knkFile = f;
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }

    private String getChecksumOfFile() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm.toString());

        // Get knkFile input stream for reading the knkFile content
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(this.knkFile)) {
            // Create byte array to read data in chunks
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192];
            int bytesCount = 0;

            // Read knkFile data and update in message digest
            while ((bytesCount = fis.read(byteArray)) != -1) {
                digest.update(byteArray, 0, bytesCount);
            }
        }

        //Get the hash's bytes
        byte[] bytes = digest.digest();

        // bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
        // Convert it to hexadecimal format
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<String> createTask() {
        return new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                return getChecksumOfFile();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Is it okay to create 4 services? Or can I create 1 service with 4 tasks? How can I synchronize them all and wait for all results before inserting the information in the database?

Thanks.

## Edit

I tried following after an answer.

```
public class ChecksumCalculationTask extends Task<String> {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    private final KnkFile knkFile;
    private final Algorithm algorithm;

    public ChecksumCalculationTask(KnkFile f, Algorithm algorithm) {
        this.knkFile = f;
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }

    private String getChecksumOfFile() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm.toString());

        // Get knkFile input stream for reading the knkFile content
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(this.knkFile)) {
            // Create byte array to read data in chunks
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192];
            int bytesCount = 0;

            // Read knkFile data and update in message digest
            while ((bytesCount = fis.read(byteArray)) != -1) {
                digest.update(byteArray, 0, bytesCount);
            }
        }

        //Get the hash's bytes
        byte[] bytes = digest.digest();

        // bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
        // Convert it to hexadecimal format
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public KnkFile getKnkFile() {
        return this.knkFile;
    }

    public Algorithm getAlgorithm() {
        return this.algorithm;
    }

    @Override
    protected String call() throws Exception {
        return getChecksumOfFile();
    }
}
```

`dev.kanka.checksumsharer.utils.FileUtil#handleNewFiles`

```
public static void handleNewFiles(List<File> files) {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Algorithm.values().length);
        List<ChecksumCalculationTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        for (File file : files) {
            KnkFile knkFile = new KnkFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

            tasks.add(new ChecksumCalculationTask(knkFile, Algorithm.SHA_256));
            tasks.add(new ChecksumCalculationTask(knkFile, Algorithm.SHA_512));
            tasks.add(new ChecksumCalculationTask(knkFile, Algorithm.SHA3_384));
            tasks.add(new ChecksumCalculationTask(knkFile, Algorithm.SHA3_512));
        }

        List<Future<String>> futures = exec.invokeAll(tasks);

        // Create a `Task` that waits until they're finished and processes them all
        Task<Void> processCompletedTasks = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // block until tasks complete
                for (Future<String> f : futures) {
                    f.get();
                }
                // process completed tasks
                for (ChecksumCalculationTask task : tasks) {
                    KnkFile knkFile = task.getKnkFile();
                    String checksum = task.getValue();
                    Algorithm algorithm = task.getAlgorithm();

                    // ... whatever you need here, note this is on background thread
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        exec.submit(processCompletedTasks);
        exec.shutdown();
    }
```

It looks logic for me but I got an compiler error in IntelliJ because of the `exec.invokeAll`-call: `reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that ChecksumCalculationTask conforms to Callable<T>`.

## Edit 2

I have no compiler errors anymore but a new weird problem. All debug messages are shown in console until the programm is reaching the line where I commented `// SEEME`.

```
public static void handleNewFiles(List<File> files) {
        logger.debug("handleNewFiles()");

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        List<ChecksumCalculationTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>(Algorithm.values().length);

        for (File file : files) {
            logger.debug("handle file {}", file);

            KnkFile knkFile = new KnkFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

            for (Algorithm algorithm : Algorithm.values()) {
                ChecksumCalculationTask task = new ChecksumCalculationTask(knkFile, algorithm);
                logger.debug(task);
                tasks.add(task);
                exec.execute(task);
            }
        }

        logger.debug("All files were added to the tasks queue and processing was started.");

        // Create a `Task` that waits until all `ChecksumCalculationTask`s finished and processes them all
        Task<Void> processCompletedTasks = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                logger.debug("processCompletedTasks#call()");

                // block until tasks complete
                for (Future<?> f : tasks) {
                    f.get();
                    logger.debug("Future f: " + f);
                }

                logger.debug("Process completed tasks now...");

                // process completed tasks
                for (ChecksumCalculationTask task : tasks) {

                    logger.debug("Process completed task {}", task);

                    // SEEMEE ... it seems nothing below is executed... why? No debug messages, no DB insertion...
                    String checksum = task.getValue();
                    logger.debug("checksum: " + checksum);
                    Algorithm algorithm = task.getAlgorithm();
                    logger.debug("algorithm: " + algorithm);
                    KnkFile knkFile = task.getKnkFile();
                    logger.debug(knkFile);

                    switch(task.getAlgorithm()) {
                        case SHA_256 -> knkFile.setSha256(task.getValue());
                        case SHA_512 -> knkFile.setSha512(task.getValue());
                        case SHA3_384 -> knkFile.setSha3384(task.getValue());
                        case SHA3_512 -> knkFile.setSha3512(task.getValue());
                    }

                    FileDAO.insertFile(knkFile);
                }

                logger.debug("end call();");

                return null;
            }
        };
        exec.submit(processCompletedTasks);
        exec.shutdown();
    }
```

Console:

```
2022-01-22 01:04:31 INFO  ChecksumSharerApplication:72 - Dropped files: [D:\Musik\!Amirap\X Zibit - X.mp3]
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:56 - handleNewFiles()
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:62 - handle file D:\Musik\!Amirap\X Zibit - X.mp3
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:68 - dev.kanka.checksumsharer.hash.ChecksumCalculationTask@7bf96ac3[Not completed, task = javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable@6c1b122d]
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:68 - dev.kanka.checksumsharer.hash.ChecksumCalculationTask@1ff9f582[Not completed, task = javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable@2bc700ad]
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:68 - dev.kanka.checksumsharer.hash.ChecksumCalculationTask@4727494a[Not completed, task = javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable@54f6e911]
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:68 - dev.kanka.checksumsharer.hash.ChecksumCalculationTask@6a594eea[Not completed, task = javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable@90490ba]
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:74 - All files were added to the tasks queue and processing was started.
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:80 - processCompletedTasks#call()
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:85 - Future f: dev.kanka.checksumsharer.hash.ChecksumCalculationTask@7bf96ac3[Completed normally]
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:85 - Future f: dev.kanka.checksumsharer.hash.ChecksumCalculationTask@1ff9f582[Completed normally]
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:85 - Future f: dev.kanka.checksumsharer.hash.ChecksumCalculationTask@4727494a[Completed normally]
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:85 - Future f: dev.kanka.checksumsharer.hash.ChecksumCalculationTask@6a594eea[Completed normally]
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:88 - Process completed tasks now...
2022-01-22 01:04:31 DEBUG FileUtil:93 - Process completed task dev.kanka.checksumsharer.hash.ChecksumCalculationTask@7bf96ac3[Completed normally]
```

Can't explain why...?

Comment: I published the whole code now https://github.com/kankadev/checksum-sharer-javafx

Answer (score 2):

Make your checksum calculator a `Task`, instead of a `Service`:

```
public class ChecksumCalculatorTask extends Task<String> {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    private final KnkFile knkFile;
    private final Algorithm algorithm;

    public ChecksumCalculatorService(KnkFile f, Algorithm algorithm) {
        this.knkFile = f;
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }

    public KnkFile getKnkFile() {
        return knkFile;
    }

    private String getChecksumOfFile() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        // ...

    }

    @Override
    protected String call() throws Exception {
        return getChecksumOfFile();
    }
}
```

Create an executor:

```
private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedTheadPool() ;
```

Now you can submit the tasks to the executor:

```
public static void handleNewFiles(List<File> files) {

    List<ChecksumCalculatorTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    for (java.io.File file : files) {
        KnkFile knkFile = new KnkFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

        ChecksumCalculatorTask sha256task = new ChecksumCalculatorTask(knkFile, Algorithm.SHA_256);
        tasks.add(sha256Task);
        sha256task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            logger.debug(knkFile);
        });
        exec.execute(task);
    }

    
    // Create a `Task` that waits until they're finished and processes tham all:

    Task<Void> processCompletedTasks = new Task<>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            // block until tasks complete:
            for (Future<?> f : tasks) {
                f.get();
            }
            // process completed tasks:
            for (ChecksumCalculatorTask task : tasks) {
                KnkFile file = task.getKnkFile() ;
                String checksum = task.getValue();
                // ... whatever you need here, note this is on background thread
            }
        }
    };
    exec.submit(processCompletedTasks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have an error. See my edit in original thread. Thanks. PS: Is a fixed thread pool maybe better for my purpose?

Comment: @kanka.dev Sorry, for some reason I thought `Task` implemented `Callable`. See edits; since `Task` is a `Future` you can simply execute each task in the executor and then, in a background thread, call `get()` on all the tasks.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a curious bug now. See Edit 2.